# IntelliJ Idea 2016.3 EAP change to stable

Tags: intellij-idea

I've installed IntelliJ Idea 2016.3 EAP.

In update settings I can't switch to stable update channel.
Is there a possibility to do this without uninstalling IntelliJ Idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can not.

But check out https://www.jetbrains.com/toolbox/ for easier updates in JetBrains software. As an added bonus, you can effortlessly switch between EAP and stable builds for all their tools there.